# Trying to find out where and if there is mapping between URL and servlet in SalesForce

Tags: apex

When opening the following hyperlink: 
https://www.emerchantpay.com/maf/sponsored?name=Test&volume=20000&leadId=MDBRNTYwMDAwMDEwMzFMRUFR

a specific form is loaded in the browser.

I would like to change the data in the generated form.

For that particular purpose I would like to know the exact servlet which is invoked when the above URL is pressed.

Could you please advise how can I find out which servlet is invoked.

Is there a mapping between the URLs and the servlets.

The mapping for the standard java web applications is in the web.xml file.

Is there such or similar file in the structure or context of SalseForce?

Comment: My answer is specifically to answer your question of Web.xml and mapping URLS. The feature you have there on that link looks like what is called Web to Lead. Take a look here. Web to Lead allows 3rd party websites to post information to Salesforce.com.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&language=en

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no web.xml equivalent on the Force.com platform.

URL Endpoints do have some common mapping patterns.

**Standard Page Layout** - You can think of this as the out of box "form" for a SFDC object (which you can think of as somewhat similar to a SQL Table).
https://podX.salesforce.com/**000XXXXX0000XXX** - Standard Page Layout. The 0000XXXX000XXX is the specific Record ID.

**Custom Visualforce Page** - This is the Force.com equivalent of JSF pages. The URL has the format https://podX.salesforce.com/**apex/CustomVFPage**.  You use Apex Controllers to populate the data (Similar to ViewBeans or BackingBeans in JEE). You can override the behavior of a standard page layout to point to a Visualforce page in the Setup Menu for an Object.

**REST Endpoints** - Force.com has a robust set of API's including all the custom objects (similar to SQL Tables). The format is https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/SObjects/OBJECTNAME and allows full access to Query, Create, Read, Update, and Delete records programmatically.

Additional Reference Material

Page Layouts - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessing_layout_standard.htm

Visualforce - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf

REST API https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf